# How do I get an element name in cheerio with node.js

Tags: html, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

How do I get an element's name in cheerio?

The jQuery equivalent would be `.attr('name')` but that returns `undefined` in cheerio.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's only one case, I suppose, when `$someElement.attr('name')` returns `undefined` - if there's NO *attribute* `name` on that element. For example...

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    $ = cheerio.load(
      '<input id="one" type="input" /><input id="two" name="some_name" />');

console.log( $('#one').attr('name') ); // undefined
console.log( $('#two').attr('name') ); // some_name
```

Note that `<name>` attribute is only applicable to the following set of elements (MDN):

```
<a>, <applet>, <button>, <form>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>, 
<input>, <map>, <meta>, <object>, <param>, <select>, <textarea>
```

---

To get the name of the element itself (it's [**tagName**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.tagName) actually, but Cheerio abstracts it), use `name` property of the underlying element wrapped in Cheerio container, like this:

```
console.log( $('#one')[0].name ); // input 
console.log( $('#two')[0].name ); // input
```

Comment: I'm looking for the element's name not the attribute name. 

e.g. <input /> = "input"

Comment: Then, like I said, you should use `$('someSelector')[0].name`.