# Is there any way to figure out exactly which tags are present on a webpage?

Tags: html, node.js, dom, tags

I was wondering if there is a way to get a list of tags present on a given page. I mean, can we scan the DOM of a page and make a list of unique tags that are present?
I am working in node.js for this, but I would like to know if there is a solution in any language for this.

Update-
    I am using the request module in nodejs to get a response html and then cheerio to select elements. Can I get a tag's name using cheerio maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the collection of all tags inside an HTML page,
you can simply do this `document.getElementsByTagName('*')` or `document.querySelectorAll('*')` in javascript.

Comment: I am not working with a front-end, so I cannot use document. I am loading a page using request. can I use querySelectorAll() on the response html?

Comment: found the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937383/how-do-i-get-an-element-name-in-cheerio-with-node-js

Thanks though :)