# Selecting an html node's text content with htmlparser2 in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, html-parsing

I want to parse some html with [htmlparser2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlparser2) module for Node.js. My task is to find a precise element by its ID and extract its text content.

I have read the [documentation](https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2/wiki/Parser-options) (quite limited) and I know how to setup my parser with the `onopentag` function but it only gives access to the tag name and its attributes (I cannot see the text). The `ontext` function extracts all text nodes from the given html string, but ignores all markup.

So here's my code.

```js
const htmlparser = require("htmlparser2");
const file = '<h1 id="heading1">Some heading</h1><p>Foobar</p>';

const parser = new htmlparser.Parser({
  onopentag: function(name, attribs){
    if (attribs.id === "heading1"){
      console.log(/*how to extract text so I can get "Some heading" here*/);
    }
  },
   
  ontext: function(text){
    console.log(text); // Some heading \n Foobar
  }
});

parser.parseComplete(file);
```

I expect the output of the function call to be `'Some heading'`. I believe that there is some obvious solution but somehow it misses my mind.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use this specific library? Do you have to? For some people, something like Cheerio is a bit easier to use since it has a jQuery like interface you can leverage.

Comment: Thank for the question. No, I don’t have to use this particular library, but it seems pretty popular and fast. Regarding Cheerio, I don’t know jQuery, so it doesn’t look very friendly to me.

Comment: I'll write something up for you. I don't think a parser is the way to go about this.

Comment: I added an answer for you. The library you are using above is more about inspecting the structure of things and it's support for querying is kinda second class from what I understand. I left both examples for you though so you can learn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this using the library you asked about:

```
const htmlparser = require('htmlparser2');
const domUtils = require('domutils');

const file = '<h1 id="heading1">Some heading</h1><p>Foobar</p>';

var handler = new htmlparser.DomHandler(function(error, dom) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('Parsing had an error');
    return;
  } else {
    const item = domUtils.findOne(element => {
      const matches = element.attribs.id === 'heading1';
      return matches;
    }, dom);

    if (item) {
      console.log(item.children[0].data);
    }
  }
});

var parser = new htmlparser.Parser(handler);
parser.write(file);
parser.end();
```

The output you will get is "Some Heading". However, you will, in my opinion, find it easier to just use a querying library that is meant for it. You of course, don't need to do this, but you can note how much simpler the following code is: [How do I get an element name in cheerio with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937383/how-do-i-get-an-element-name-in-cheerio-with-node-js)

Cheerio OR a querySelector API such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser if you prefer the native query selectors is much more lean.

You can compare that code to something more lean, such as the `node-html-parser` which supports simply querying:

```
const { parse } = require('node-html-parser');

const file = '<h1 id="heading1">Some heading</h1><p>Foobar</p>';
const root = parse(file);
const text = root.querySelector('#heading1').text;
console.log(text);
```

Comment: The `node-html-parser` module looks indeed friendlier. Thanks for tackling the question as it is and providing an alternative as well. Much obliged!